# Method to simplify this long expression

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

How can I simplify this long expression:

$-a^3(d-b)(d-c)(c-b)+b^3(d-a)(d-c)(c-a)-c^3(d-a)(d-b)(b-a)+d^3(c-a)(b-a)(c-b)$

I know that it is equal to $(d-a)(d-b)(d-c)(c-a)(c-b)(b-a)$ but i have no idea how to get to it

My current option is to expand the expression to something like this:

$bc^2d^3-ac^2d^3-b^2cd^3+a^2cd^3+ab^2d^3-a^2bd^3-bc^3d^2+ac^3d^2+b^3cd^2-a^3cd^2-ab^3d^2+a^3bd^2+b^2c^3d-a^2c^3d-b^3c^2d+a^3c^2d+a^2b^3d-a^3b^2d-ab^2c^3+a^2bc^3+ab^3c^2-a^3bc^2-a^2b^3c+a^3b^2c$

But something like that will take a lot of time and also it's still not that easy to  simplify it.

I think that the solution is related to the fact that some parts of the results are already in the initial expression, but i don't know how to continue from there.

Thanks

Comment: It looks that Wolfram itself don't find this simplification... http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Simplify+-a%5E3%28d-b%29%28d-c%29%28c-b%29%2Bb%5E3%28d-a%29%28d-c%29%28c-a%29-c%5E3%28d-a%29%28d-b%29%28b-a%29%2Bd%5E3%28c-a%29%28b-a%29%28c-b%29

Comment: This query gives the answer:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+-a%5E3%28d-b%29%28d-c%29%28c-b%29%2Bb%5E3%28d-a%29%28d-c%29%28c-a%29-c%5E3%28d-a%29%28d-b%29%28b-a%29%2Bd%5E3%28c-a%29%28b-a%29%28c-b%29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** The expression is equal to zero when any two of the parameters $a,b,c,d$ are equal. Can you use this, the remainder theorem and the degrees of the expression to get a result?

---

**Remainder Theorem**: If $f(x)$ is a polynomial and $f(a) = 0$, then $x-a \mid f$.

---

**Bigger Hint:**

> Consider your expression as a polynomial $f$ in $a$. Show that 
> $$f(b)=f(c ) = f(d) = 0.$$ This tells you that $(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)$ divides your expression. Now view your expression as a polynomial in $b$, $c$, $d$, for the remaining factors.

Comment: Thanks! I knew that there must be an easier solution, but how can i prove that there are no other results as well?

Comment: Treating the expression as a polynomial in four variables, two polynomials with the same roots must be equal up to a constant. So any other factorisation must have the same factors, give or take minus signs.